# Is this PHP? If so, why do for loops not work?

Tags: php, for-loop, cmd

I'm doing the matrix rain effect in command prompt, and I want to make it change colors but if I do this:

```
color 0a
:start
echo %random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%

color 0b

echo %random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%

goto start
```

The colors change far to fast. I want them to change every 5 seconds or so. To do this, I tried using a for loop, thinking this is php, but the command prompt simply opens and closes quickly. This is what I'm putting in my code for the for loop way of changing colors:

```
color 0a
:start


for ($x = 0; $x < 51; x++)
{
echo %random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%
}

color 0b

for ($y = 0; $y < 51; y++)
{
echo %random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%
}
```

I have no knowledge of PHP, and don't know if it's on my computer or not but it seems like some kind of it is because the first code block works... sorry for the unclear question, but I don't really know what I'm doing. How would I make a for loop work in this program? Am I even doing right? Or is this just some low grade version of PHP that comes with all computers?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php

Comment: `Because it works, it must be PHP` - I like this reasoning ;)

Comment: It looks similar to php, I never said that I knew it was php beyond a reasonable doubt

Comment: looks like MS-DOS command. how are you running this script?

Comment: if it is ms dos command and you are using windows 2000 or above, you can use `timeout /t 5 /nobreak > NUL` to sleep for 5 secs

Comment: I know about the timeout thing, but that literally stops the numbers from streaming for 5 seconds it doesn't make the colors stay what they are for 5 seconds and then move on to the next color so on so forth, how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't remember ms-dos batch script much now, i have not used it for past 20+ years. but here is something you can try and build on. I have added a delay for color switching.

```
@ECHO OFF
set T=0
set inc=1

:start
color 0a
echo %random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%
set /a T=%T%+%inc%
if not %T%==500 goto start
set T=0
:nxtClr
color 0b

echo %random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%
set /a T=%T%+%inc%
if not %T%==500 goto nxtClr
set T=0

goto start
```

PS: I don't know if you can get the precision of seconds and ms with dos batch script.